# Design optional parameters for routes with leading question mark

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to save the  `table_name=Unemployment+rate&start_date=2012-01-29&end_date=2013-03-29%27` in parameters variable,

I can NOT let user  change their URL request, so their url request must has the question mark in the leading of parameters.

How could I change the Rails route rule to save all parameter in `parameters` thanks

`http://HOST/materials/?table_name=Unemployment+rate&start_date=2012-01-29&end_date=2013-03-29%27`

## routes.rb

```
get 'materials/(:parameters)'  => "query#materials"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be done with POST variables, not in a GET requests.

I have a model called `Service` and the routes for it look like:

```
╔══════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════╗
║ GET  ║ /services(.:format) ║ services#index  ║
║ POST ║ /services(.:format) ║ services#create ║
╚══════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════╝
```

What that means is when I POST to `/services` my controller's `create` function will be called. If I send a GET request, my controller's `index` function is what will be called.

You should probably look into rail's form helpers like thee `form_for` method:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html